# iPython Console in spyder locks Windows file explorer

Tags: python, tkinter, spyder

I'm having an issue with writing text files in the spyder IDE.
My environment is :

- Spyder version: 5.1.1 None
- Python version: 3.7.9 64-bit
- Qt version: 5.12.10
- PyQt5 version: 5.12.3
- Operating System: Windows 10

I'm using tkinter to bring up a filedialog to pick an input file

Do some data processing then store the results in a CSV file.

What I'm seeing is, not every, time but most times. When I try and open the output CSV file using the windows file explorer. The file explorer won't respond. Killing the console in spyder will immediately unlock the file explorer.  This doesn't happen if I run my code in an external power shell or command prompt, or if I set the Spyder run configuration to "Execute in an external system terminal".

This is annoying when trying to develop/debug, doesn't seem to affect the application when run outside of the Spyder Console.

Here's a code snippet showing what I'm trying to do.

```
import datetime
import csv
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


rt = tk.Tk()
rt.withdraw()
    
filePath = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    
tree = ET.parse(filePath)
root = tree.getroot()
    
notesNodes = root.findall('.//Name[.="ScanNotes"]..')
Notes = notesNodes[0][1].text
Notes = Notes.rsplit('\n')
    
    
def StoreCSV (filePointer, DataHeader, Data):
    localData =[]
    localData = Data.copy()
    localData.insert(0,DataHeader) # add header to file
    write = csv.writer(file)
    write.writerow(localData)
    
csvfilePath = filePath +".csv"
file = open(csvfilePath,'w',newline='')
    
with file as writer:
    StoreCSV(file, 'Scan Notes', Notes)
```

I see the same behaviour in Spyder 4.2.5 that is installed as part of an Anaconda install.